# Why does the Twitter API search endpoint only show a max of 15 results when sorting by popular tweets?

Tags: twitter, twitter-search, twitter-rest-api

When using the search endpoint, I am only getting a max of 15 results, no matter how popular of a search query I use. Setting count to 100 does not make a difference, however it does when sorting by most recent. Does anybody else experience this? Is it a possible bug or on purpose?

Here's an example call:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=pluto&result_type=popular&count=100
```

Docs: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

Answer (score 1):

I have actually the same problem. I can just tell you, if your request has more result than 15, that you can "repeat" the request checking the last block "search_metadata" in the json file. You get directly the next request to do under "next_results". If there are non more results you will not see this part of code.